# Unable to connect to Parse server from Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, parse-server

##### Prerequisites

Host: localhost

Docker version: 20.10.11

Parse node client version: 2.19.0

Parse server version: 4.10.4

*docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    image: app:latest
    depends_on:
      - parse-platform
    environment:
      - PARSE_SERVER_URL=https://parse-platform:1337/parse
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=123446
      - PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=M234011
    ports:
      - "1330:1330"
    command: ["yarn", "run", "dev-server"] // dev-server runs nodemon index.js
    networks:
      - customnetwork

  parse-platform:
    build:
      context: ../parse-platform
    image: parse-platform:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - PORT=1337
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=123446
      - PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=M234011
      - PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI=mongodb://db:27017/app
      - PARSE_SERVER_MOUNT_POINT=/parse 
      - PARSE_SERVER_URL=https://parse-platform:1337/parse
      - PARSE_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL=https://localhost:1337/parse
      - PARSE_SERVER_DIRECT_ACCESS=false
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    command: ["yarn", "run", "dev-server"]
    networks:
      - customnetwork

  db:
    image: mongo:bionic
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - customnetwork
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: parse-db
        target: /data/db

networks:
  customnetwork:

volumes:
  parse-db:
```

*parse-platform Dockerfile*

```
FROM node:14

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/parse-platform

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 1337
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]

USER node
```

*parse-platform (aka parse-server) js constructor configuration*

```js
const config = {
  appName: "Parse Server Demo",
  appId: process.env.PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID || "123456789",
  masterKey: process.env.PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY || "",
  databaseURI: databaseUri || "mongodb://localhost:27017/db",
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + "/cloud/main.js",
  port: process.env.PORT || "1337",
  serverURL: process.env.PARSE_SERVER_URL || "https://localhost:1337/parse",
  publicServerURL:
    process.env.PARSE_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL || "https://localhost:1337/parse",
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: [], // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  },
};
```

##### Actual result

After running `docker compose up -d`, parse-platform container throws a warning:

```
WARNING, Unable to connect to 'https://localhost:1337/parse'. Cloud code and push notifications may be unavailable!
```

##### Additional research

1. I can reach out to parse-server via wget or Postman request through REST API. That means, parse-server is available, but not accessible inside Docker container
2. Tried to replace `PARSE_SERVER_URL` with `https://localhost:1337/parse` with the assumption Compose networking works not how i expected. But the same warning appears.
3. Starting `parse-server` as a node process in CLI works without warnings: `node index.js`

##### Expected result

After running `docker compose up -d`, parse-server starts without a connection warning.

What adjustments should i take to fix that? Or maybe additional research?

Thank to all of you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide more details about the image being used by the `parse-platform` container? I'm a little confused why the `parse-platform` container is throwing that error; is it running both a server and client in the same container? Or is the error actually coming from the `app` container?

Comment: PARSE_SERVER_URL= https://customnetwork:1337/parse

Comment: @larsks I've added an additional info about Dockerfile, from which image of `parse-platform` was built, hope this sheds more light. `app` service is a node.js client, and `parse-platform` is a parse server instance, which is throws the warning. These are two separate containers.

Comment: @RavindraBagale setting URL without a host doesn't work.